# Linear-gradient not working in IE 11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a css rule that works fine in chrome, firefox and used to work in IE. Now my seemingly valid css is not working.

```
.s-tour {
/*border-radius: 5px;*/
margin: 0 auto;
width: 250px;
height: 200px;
line-height: 100px;
font-weight: 600;
font-size: 18px;
box-shadow: 0 0 7px rgba(1, 1, 1, .8);
border: solid thin #555;
color: #E0E0E0;
background: #555;
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #555 0%, #eee 100%);
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #777, #666);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#555555 0%,#666666 100%);
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #777, #666);
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #777, #666);
}
```

I feel like both `background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #555 0%, #eee 100%);` or `-ms-background-image: linear-gradient(top,#555555 0%,#666666 100%);` should be working for IE 11 yet the the IE inspector puts a fuzzy red line under it and anything else I try.

I checked a working gradient on a google page and `background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top,#f5f5f5,#f1f1f1);` was working fine, yet even that exact line would not work on my site.

I've tried all variations I can think of in terms of property,prefix and values, including every relevant answer on stack overflow and am now stumped, wondering if it is a DOM issue or bug or something simple.

Comment: you can use [this site](http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator) to generate `css gradient`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try adding this line to the end of your class:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#555555, endColorstr=#666666);
```

Comment: This works. Im surprised, I thought this was IE pre 10 syntax

Comment: I was only able to get it working after enclosing colors in single quote like 'filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#555555', endColorstr='#666666');`  +1

Answer (score 9):

So the problem I really had was that I was not telling IE to render the page using the latest standards of css. 
Adding `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />` to the `<head>` block fixed most of my problems.

Answer (score 8):

What has worked for me in IE11 is to correctly use the CSS3 linear-gradient property (http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)

An example:

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #FFF 0%, #EEE 100%);
```

After that I didn't need to use any meta tags or old filter syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Using  `180deg` instead of `top` solved the same problem for me.

Previously tried `filter` and already had `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />`