# How to add background linear-gradient to iOS Safari, Mac Safari, Edge, and IE11?

Tags: html, css, background, linear-gradients

We are attempting to use `background: linear-gradient()` to get the following output. However, we are running into a problem where the css is not being applied to the following browsers.

**Question:**

How can we get it to work on all browsers?

**Browsers with issues**

- Mac High Sierra Safari 11.1
- IE11
- Microsoft Edge 44.17763.771.0
- Safari on iOS (v12)

**What we tried**

```css
.box { 
  padding:20px;
  display:inline-block;
  border-right:2px solid #000;
  border-left:2px solid #000;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to left ,#000 10px,transparent 10px 30px,#000 0) top,
    linear-gradient(to right,#000 10px,transparent 10px 30px,#000 0) bottom;
  background-size:100% 2px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
Some text inside
</div>
```

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26522101/linear-gradient-not-working-in-ie-11/26522234

Comment: You can use https://cssgradient.io/ just click the "Max Compatibility (IE 6+)" checkbox and it'll generate the code for you. There are several other similar tools out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double position color stops are not supported in IE/Edge and Safari < v13.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient

Simply change your code as such:

```css
background:
    linear-gradient(to left ,#000 10px,transparent 10px, transparent 30px, #000 0) top,
    linear-gradient(to right,#000 10px,transparent 10px, transparent 30px, #000 0) bottom;
```

Comment: i have found out the hard way....its basically not supported. https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-css_types_image_gradient_repeating-linear-gradient_doubleposition